# How to retrieve google calendar events in Android TV app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-calendar-api, android-tv

I'm currently working on Android TV app, I need to retrieve google calendar events and show it in the TV app UI. I used the ContentResolver and calendar events URI  "Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events")" to get the events, but unable to retrieve the events and its showing as an empty list from the cursor. The same code is working fine in Android mobile app, because it is retrieving the events from the calendar app, that was not available in the Android TV.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that an Android TV device has a calendar app, let alone one that the user has configured for their calendars.

Comment: with same account logged in to the Android TV should list the events. But I'm getting the empty cursor list.

    val cursor = this.baseContext.contentResolver.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            null)

Comment: The above code is working for mobile not for TV. can anyone pls help to resolve this.

Comment: "with same account logged in to the Android TV should list the events" -- I have no idea how you came to this conclusion.